# this.setState is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I keep seeing answers that say to use => or .bind(this) but neither of those solutions worked.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class MyWeatherApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {};
}

getInitialState() {
  return {
    zip: '',
    forecast: null,
  };
}

_handleTextChange(event) {
  var zip = event.nativeEvent.text;
  this.setState({zip: zip});
}
```

Solution:

```
_handleTextChange = (event) => {
  var zip = event.nativeEvent.text;
  this.setState({zip: zip});
  alert('click');
}
```

Comment: How are you attempting to bind `this` at the moment? It's not clear from your code.

Comment: Can we see the whole code ?

Comment: first in es6 there is nothing called getInitialState() in react. you have to do it in this.state={zip: '', forecast: null}

Comment: I am following udemy course. React native is changing so fast that the courses can't even keep up with the syntax changes.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

When you `extend` `React.Component` with ES2015 class syntax you need to bind your action handlers to a context of your class.

Try this: `onChange={e => _handleTextChange(e)}`

Generally, it's better not to use arrow functions or `bind` methods inside `render` as it generates a new copy of the function on any `render` call. Move function declaration to the `class constructor`.

I personally prefer to use arrow functions as class properties in this case

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {

  handleClick = () => {
    // your logic
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me</button>
    );
  }
}
```

It's not a part of ES2015 specification but [babel stage-0 preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/) supports this syntax

You can read more about context binding in React in [this article](http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/08/16/react-and-es6-part3.html)

Comment: "Generally, it's better not to use arrow functions or bind methods inside render as it generates a new copy of the function on any render call. Move function declaration to the class constructor." What you mean here ? So my way of `onChange={e => _handleTextChange(e)}` Is not the best way ?

Comment: @EmanuelQuimper if the child component is pure, it will most likely use a shallow equality check on its props to see if any of them are different to avoid re-rendering if there are no changes.  If you create your lamba method right inside your render, you create a new `onChange` each time you render and the child component will see this "new" property and re-render when it did not need to.

Comment: @Brandon Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I was unable to import the button component. Do I need to install it via NPM?

Comment: No, button is just an html element. Check if your jsx transpiler works correctly. Ow I see. If you use React Native it should be `TouchableElement` instead

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. It was a real head-scratcher when trying to go through the Advance example of `react-native-gifted-chat` and getting `'this.setState' is undefined`.

Comment: Is this syntax supported on babel stage 2 or 3? I don't feel safe using stage 0 or 1 as the new feature is still on very early stages.

Answer (score 21):

Let me write this in detail. As I had to waste a lot of time in researching it & I don't want anyone to repeat this...

If you dont use Arrow Function you have to bind `this` like Line '9'

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {

  handleButtonClick(){
    console.log("Hello from here");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleButtonClick.bind(this)}>Click me</button>
    );
  }
}
```

Another way is using ES6 Arrow function. You need not bind 'this' in this case. Installing 'babel stage-1 preset' will support this.

Run the command below in your project:

`npm i babel-preset-stage-1 --save`

Your .babelrc will look like this. Specially 'stage-1' in the preset.

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-1"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
    }
  }
}
```

Your component will be like this, as I said:

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {

      handleButtonClick = () => {
        console.log("Hello from here");
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <button onClick={this.handleButtonClick}>Click me</button>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Is this supported on babel preset 2 or 3? I don't feel safe using stage-1 preset as the new feature is still on very early stages.

Answer (score 7):

The problem was: I had that **ERROR**: this.setState is not a function

Given i was binding my function to the state in component constructor, like this:

```
 this.getRequestData = this.getRequestData.bind(this);
```

and my function was:

```
getRequestData(){
    axios.post('http://example.com/getInfo', jsonData)
                        .then(function (res) {
                            console.log(res);
                        })
                        .catch(function (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        });
                        this.setState({ stateVaribale });
                    })
}
```

**the solution** is to use `arrow functions` instead of using `keyword`function in the axios request, cause it's confusing to react to refer to the **function in axios request** instead of the **component state**.

```
getRequestData(){
axios.post('http://example.com/getInfo', jsonData)
                        .then(res => {
                        console.log(res);
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.log(error);
                        });
                        this.setState({ stateVaribale });
                    })}
```

Answer (score 5):

also you can bind this in `constructor` like this

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleButtonClick = this.handleButtonClick.bind(this);
 }
  handleButtonClick(){
    console.log("Hello from here");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleButtonClick}>Click me</button>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in react native, we got this error when we use axios, as an example

```
    componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('https://the request url')
    .then( function(response) {
      this.setState({products:response.data.products});
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
}
```

if we try like this we got :

undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.setState')

so how we can fix this, we can fix it using arrow function like this

```
componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('https://the request url')
        .then( (response)=> {
          this.setState({products:response.data.products});
        })
        .catch((error)=> {
          console.log(error);
        })
    }
```

this will solve the problem, hope this will helpful

Answer (score 1):

you need to bind your action otherwise you can see error called undefined in your browser
there are three methods for binding your action

1. bind the handler in the render method
   this.chngHandler.bind(this)

for eg-

```
export class EventBind extends Component{
constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
        msg:'hello'
    }
}
chngHandler(){
    this.setState({
         msg:'Good bye'
    })
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            {this.state}
            <button onClick={this.chngHandler.bind(this)}>click</button>
        </div>
    )
 } }
```

2. arrow function approach in render  `()=>this.EventHandler()`

for example-

```
export class EventBind extends Component{
constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
        msg:'hello'
    }
}
chngHandler(){
    this.setState({
         msg:'Good bye'
    })
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            {this.state}
            <button onClick={()=>this.chngHandler()}>click</button>
        </div>
    )
}}`
```

3.Binding the event handler in the constructor
`this.EventHandler = this.EventHandler.bind(this)`
for example-:

```
export class EventBind extends Component{
constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
        msg:'hello'
    }
    this.chngHandler = this.chngHandler.bind(this)
}
chngHandler(){
    this.setState({
         msg:'Good bye'
    })
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            {this.state}
            <button onClick={this.chngHandler}>click me </button>
        </div>
    )
}}
```

because the binding happens once in the constructor this is better than a binding in the render method

3rd approach can also be done like this -:

```
export class EventBind extends Component{
constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
        msg:'hello'
    }
    this.chngHandler = this.chngHandler.bind(this)
}
// chngHandler(){
//     this.setState({
//          msg:'Good bye'
//     })
// }
chngHandler = ()=>{
    this.setState({
        msg:'Good Bye'
    })
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            {this.state}
            <button onClick={this.chngHandler}>click me </button>
        </div>
    )
}}
```

Comment: Thank you I tried all options which you shared in this still getting same error. setState undefined.

Answer (score 0):

works for react-native too when you use fat arrow functions inside the methods you are invoking another function.
eg
`.then((response) => {
this.setState({....})
}`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are using this inside an api call like axios request There are cases where your 'this' context remains to be undefined.
Elaborating few of them here-:

`

```
import react from 'React'
class Test extends from React.Component {
constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
data: '',
error: ''
}
}
componentDidMount() {
url = 'http://abc.go.com';
axios.get(url).then(function(resposne) {   // Everything fine till now
this.setState({ data: response });   //Oops this context is undefined
}
).catch(function(err) {
 this.setState({ error: err });       // again this context remains to be undefined
});
}
render() {
return ( <div>this.state.data</div> ) 
}
}`
```

when you will run the above code you will definitely get a type error like
setState of undefined is being called, Something similar to this.

How can you solve this?
There are two methods that you can follow to solve this particular type of question-:

First one is you can define a variable inside the function where you'll be calling the api and assign it the value of 'this' and from that variable you can reference your state object.

```
import react from 'React'
class Test extends React.Component
{
  constructor() { 
     super();
     this.state = {
       data: '',
       error: ''
  };
  componentDidMount() {
   let url = 'http://abc.go.com';
   currentContext = this;   // variable to be assigned this context
   axios.get(url).then(function(resposne) {   // Everything fine till now
   currentContext.setState({ data: response });   //Oops this context is undefined
   }
   ).catch(function(err) {
  currentContext.setState({ error: err });       // again this context remains to be undefined
 });
  }
 render() {
  return ( <div>this.state.data</div> ) 
 }
 }
```

Second method that you can use is by defining arrow function in axios like given below

```
axios.get(url).then((response) => {
  this.setState({ data: response })     //will always be bound to the this context
})
```