# React-redux: this.setState is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am working on a project which is written in react-redux. I want to use the component state in component rather than global state.
My component code is:

```
import React from 'react';
import Input from 'src/containers/Input';
type StateType = {
     searchChannel: string
};
export default class AddChannelComponent extends React.Component < void,
PropsType,
void > {
     state : StateType;

     constructor(props : PropsType) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
               searchChannel: 'test'
          };
     }

     inputHandler(value) {
          console.log("text  isdddd", value);
          this.setState({searchChannel: value});  <==Error Occur Here
     }
     render() {
          return (
               <div >
                    <p>Type your input</p>
                    <div>
                         <Input inputHandler={this.inputHandler} placeholder="Search all public channels..."/>
                    </div>
               </div>
          );
     }
}
```

inputHandler function is invoked by the child component. Inside this  this.setState({searchChannel: value}) gives me error that this.setState is not a function. Although I assign a test value to the searchChannel in constructor and it's working when I console its value in render.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this.setState is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39210971/this-setstate-is-undefined)

Comment: TL;DR: You need to bind `inputHandler` to your component using any of the approaches suggested in the accepted answer above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My correction would be like this

```
import React from 'react';
import Input from 'src/containers/Input';

export default class AddChannelComponent extends React.Component{

     constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
               searchChannel: 'test'
          };
     }

     inputHandler = (value) => {
          console.log("text is dddd", value);
          this.setState({searchChannel: value});
     }
     render() {
          return (
               <div >
                    <p>Type your input</p>
                    <div>
                         <Input inputHandler={this.inputHandler} placeholder="Search all public channels..."/>
                    </div>
               </div>
          );
     }
}
```

---

#### Reason

If you pass an `instance method` (which refers to a specific context aka, accessing to `this`) you will lose its original context, because it depends on the caller.

Further info here: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

eg: `inputHandler={this.inputHandler}`

to keep the `this` you can:

- use [**bound functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) `inputHandler={this.inputHandler.bind(this)}`
- use [**arrow functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) `inputHandler={(...args) => this.inputHandler(...args)}`
- use [**Class Fields (not-standard-yet)**](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) `imputHandler = () => {}`

Comment: It's working for me. But can you tell why this is happening.

Comment: converted to a member property and arrow function, keeping the context, hence binding to instance.

Comment: @Kelltontech oh and you actually don't need to declare state type

Comment: @HanaAlaydrus This is project by my senior and this is working properly.

Comment: @Kelltontech so it's working before? then I guess the main problem is about the binding thing. reference about binding : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import Input from 'src/containers/Input';

export default class AddChannelComponent extends React.Component{

     constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
               searchChannel: 'test'
          };
     }

     inputHandler = (value) => {
          console.log("text is dddd", value);
          this.setState({searchChannel: value});
     }
     render() {
          return (
               <div >
                    <p>Type your input</p>
                    <div>
                         <Input inputHandler={this.inputHandler.bind(this)} placeholder="Search all public channels..."/>
                    </div>
               </div>
          );
     }
}
```

Comment: Please provide explanations