# Is this good practice for updating the state of a React component from a function within another function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

First of all, my code works, the question is more about good practices, and I'm new to React.

What I want to do is a simple countdown , and I had issues using

```
this.setState(...)
```

where this was not defined.

The code is now:

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.updateCountdown();
}

updateCountdown(){

    var countDownDate = new Date("Dec 14, 2019 12:00:00").getTime();

    var parent = this;        

    var x = setInterval(function(){
        var distance = countDownDate - new Date().getTime();

        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        parent.setState(state => ({
            countdown : {
                seconds : seconds,
                minutes : minutes,
                hours : hours,
                days : days
            }
        }));

        if(distance < 0){
            clearInterval(x);
        }

    }, 1000)
}
```

As you can see i do

```
var parent = this;
```

so that I can use

```
parent.setState(...)
```

within the setInterval function, but I feel there could be a cleaner way, is there ?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this.setState is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39210971/this-setstate-is-undefined)

Comment: Change `function(){` to `() => {` then you can just do `this.setState`

Comment: @Jonas Wilms Thanks, as I commented below, I should really understand arrow functions better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.updateCountdown();
}

updateCountdown(){
    var countDownDate = new Date("Dec 14, 2019 12:00:00").getTime();
    var x = setInterval(() =>{
        var distance = countDownDate - new Date().getTime();

        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

       this.setState(state => ({
            countdown : {
                seconds : seconds,
                minutes : minutes,
                hours : hours,
                days : days
            }
        }));

        if(distance < 0){
            clearInterval(x);
        }

    }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.

I better study arrow functions better because it's something I always forget.