# React binding error: FontChooser.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: this.setstate is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I keep getting an error message for

> Uncaught TypeError: this.setstate is not a function

In my code line.
I am using VSCode. I am using the Chrome Debugger because there are issues with my debugging in VSCode directly. I have tried to fix this issue but that has not made a difference and was finally never corrected. I am using LiveServer from VSCode to launch the code. There is a better configuration but I am just trying to run the code.

My code is below

HTML FILE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="Fontchoose_container"></div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <div>
    Here goes...
     <!--Programmed scripts-->
      <script src="./FontChooser.js" type="text/babel"></script> 
    ....done
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS-Script

```
class FontChooser extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {hideElement:true}
    this.text="Click on this part"
    this.size=10
//  this.handleClicks= this.handleClicks.bind(this)

    }
    handleClicks() {

        if (this.state.hideElement) {
            console.log(this.state)
            this.setstate({hideElement:false})  //ERROR HAPPENS HERE

        } else {
            this.setstate({hideElement:true})
        }
document.getElementById("checkbox").hidden=this.state.hideElement
document.getElementById("decreaseButton").hidden=this.state.hideElement
document.getElementById("fontSizeSpan").hidden=this.state.hideElement
document.getElementById("increaseButton").hidden=this.state.hideElement
document.getElementById("textSpan").hidden=this.state.hideElement

     }


    render() {
    return(<div >
            <button id="LaunchButton" onClick={this.handleClicks.bind(this)}>Click me</button>
           <input type="checkbox" id="boldCheckbox" hidden={true}/>
           <button id="decreaseButton" hidden={true}>-</button>
           { <span id="fontSizeSpan" hidden={true}>{this.props.size}</span> }
           <button id="increaseButton" hidden={true}>+</button>
           <span id="textSpan" hidden={true}>{this.props.text}</span>
           </div>
        //    hidden={false}
    );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render( <FontChooser />, document.getElementById('Fontchoose_container'))
```

I looked at several references as well as this post but the corrections do no make a difference:
[this.setState is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39210971/this-setstate-is-undefined)

I have tried correcting a bind call in several different ways and this results to an object with initialized attributes. In all the examples that I found they used `this.setstate({*/set parameters:new*/})`. In my case this causes the error and I haven't seen the reason why the call is not valid, a part from problems related to binding.

Comment: What about using `handleClicks = () => { this.setState() }` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just a typo, try using [`this.setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) (instead `setstate`).

```
if (this.state.hideElement) {
  this.setState({ hideElement: false });
}
```

Comment: That was the problem. Correct.