# Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am changing a state variable in ReactJS and then returning it in an  Element but getting an error saying:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

I am just practicing this and it is the first time I have encountered this problem. I will be grateful for your help.

**APP.JS:**

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css'



class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    alpha: "",
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ alpha: e.target.value })

  }

  render(){
    return(<>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter here..." onChange={this.handleChange} ></input>
    <h1>{this.state.alpha}</h1>
    </>)
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [this.setState is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39210971/this-setstate-is-undefined)

Comment: use constructor and use bind... this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try initializing your state inside a constructor and bind the function like below

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            alpha: ""
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            alpha: e.target.value
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Either Use the arrow function

```
handleChange=(e)=> {
    this.setState({ alpha: e.target.value })
  }
```

or bind it in the constructor like this

```
constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.state = {
   alpha: "",
 }
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
```